# How to pass a variable to a mysql query?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This one has no errors

```
cursor.execute ("update `1` set `2`='aaa' where `1`='5'")
```

This one has errors.

```
cursor.execute ("update `1` set `2`=aaa where `1`='5'")
```

The difference is, I am trying to pass the variable 'aaa' to it.

Here is the error_log of apache

> [Tue May 14 21:20:24 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'aaa' in 'field list'")

In PHP I would simply type `$aaa` in the mysql query, so the assumption was in python I would simply type `aaa`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the value of a variable, you need to write "aaa" outside the string. So, instead of:

```
cursor.execute ("update `1` set `2`=aaa where `1`='5'")
```

try:

```
cursor.execute ("update `1` set `2`= '" + aaa + "' where `1`='5'")
```

Just be aware that, if you are using python, you may need to convert your variable to string (if it holds a number for example), using:

```
str(aaa)
```

Comment: No, don't do this - now you have opened yourself to SQL injection, just like in PHP. Read @Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In php you can do `execute("Update '1' set '2'=$aaa where '1'='5'")` but you should do `execute("Update '1' set '2'=? where '1'='5'", $aaa)` with [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). But you should at least do `execute("Update '1' set '2'=".mysql_real_escape_string($aaa)." where '1'='5'")`

In Python, you use `execute("Update '1' set '2'=%s where '1'='5'", [aaa])`.

Comment: By the way, the Python DB API supports prepared statements and so do all drivers (including the MySQL one), so don't recommend the second part. See the [DB API CheatSheet](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiCheatSheet) and the [DB API FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq) entries in the Python wiki for more information. I edited your question to reflect this, and +1  by the way as well.